# How to parse output of a background process with Java?

Tags: java, postgresql

In my Java program I would like to start a PostgreSQL server. For this task I am using this code:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pgHome + "/bin/pg_ctl", "start");

Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("PGDATA", pgDataDir);

Process p = pb.start();

InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
boolean started = false;

while (!started && (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    started = line.contains("database system is ready to accept connections");
}

if (!started) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to start PostgreSQL server");
}
```

When I am starting the postgres server on the command line with the same options, I receive:

```
server starting
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2013-02-08 09:07:50 CET
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

The first line (server starting) is printed before the command returns. All following lines are printed by the background process.

My Java code only sees the first line but I want to parse the LOG messages. Is there any way to read an the input of such a background process?

I also encountered a strange and unreproducible behavior: When I debug the code, the output is parsed completely, including the LOG statements. At first I thought it is a timing issue but even waiting after starting the process did not change this.

Comment: Javadoc for Process states: "The methods that create processes may not work well for special processes on certain native platforms, such as [...] daemon processes, [...]". My *guess* is that the daemon inherits the output descriptors from pg_ctl, and Java closes those as soon as pg_ctl exits - and they are kept open while debugging the code/stopping in the middle, so you would see some log messages coming through. I would suggest to just wait for the psql port to open.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `pg_ctl` is not the actual database program. It's just a script or wrapper program which outputs the first `server starting` line but then launches the database as a background daemon process and then returns.  You cannot attach the output stream of that new process to your program.

Comment: pg_ctl is not a script. The unix file command reports "ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64".

However, if it is not possible to parse the output of the background process, why did it work in debug mode sometimes?

Comment: It still is likely a wrapper that forks the real db daemon to background.

Comment: Did you launch `pg_ctl` in "debug mode" with a flag that prevents it from going into background? If so that would account for the different behavior.

Comment: No, I did not change any parameters of the pg_ctl command but I got different results by either just running or debugging the code.

Answer (score 0):

The line you want is probably printed to stderr in which case you want to use `Process.getErrorStream ()`.

Comment: No, I already checked this. Even when I redirect the standard output stream to a file, all LOG messages appear in there. So they are not part of the error output.